# JS - Regular expression to replace all instance of string (with variable attributes)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating a component for a CMS that runs a find/replace on the response of text input, it should replace any instances of [html_image url="example"] with

I have managed to create a simple string.replace that successfully replaces a single instance (my regex is an exact match), however, I am looking for a little help refactoring my regex to find ALL instances.

```
article.content = "this is an image, {html_image id=222}. This is also an image {html_image id=111}

article.content = article.content.replace(
      new RegExp('{html_image id=222}'),
      '<img src="" />'
    );

current output = "this is an image, <img src="222"/>. This is also an image {html_image id=111}"
expected output = "this is an image, <img src="222"/>. This is also an image <img src="111"/"
```

Comment: `new RegExp('{html_image id=222}', 'g')` add the `global` tag with your regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code (adapt it to your variables):

```js
var content = "this is an image, {html_image id=222}. This is also an image {html_image id=111}";
content = content.replace(
  /{html_image id=(\d*)}/g,
  '<img src="$1" />'
);
console.log(content);
```